# Embedding Mapplotlib pie chart into Tkinter Gui Issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Embedding Mapplotlib pie chart into Tkinter Gui help!

I am trying to embed a pie chart into my Tkinter window! So far I already have a frame in mind for the graph to be embedded in, frameChartsLT. This frame also already has a canvas, *canvasChartsLT*, placed over the entire area of the frame so I was hoping to place it on either of the of these but I keep getting the error.

`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'`

I checked my entire code but I can't even find anywhere where I wrote set_canvas so I am completely lost. Any help will be truly appreciated! I am also a beginner so the simpler the explanation or fix the better for me haha!

This is the portion of my code!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

# Some in-between code that sets the frame and canvas on my window

stockListExp = [ 'AMZN' , 'AAPL', 'JETS', 'CCL', 'NCLH']
stockSplitExp = [15,25,40,10,10]


plt.pie(stockSplitExp, radius=1, labels=stockListExp,autopct='%0.2f%%', shadow=True,) # 2 decimal points after plot

figChart1 = plt.pie(stockSplitExp, radius=1, labels=stockListExp,autopct='%0.2f%%', shadow=True)
plt.axis("equal")
chart1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figChart1,frameChartsLT)
chart1.get_tk_widget().place(x=10,y=10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `matplotlib.figure.Figure` instead of `pyplot` when you combine `tkinter` with `matplotlib`. Below with modifications to your code:

```
import tkinter as tk

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = tk.Tk()
frameChartsLT = tk.Frame(root)
frameChartsLT.pack()

stockListExp = ['AMZN' , 'AAPL', 'JETS', 'CCL', 'NCLH']
stockSplitExp = [15,25,40,10,10]

fig = Figure() # create a figure object
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # add an Axes to the figure

ax.pie(stockSplitExp, radius=1, labels=stockListExp,autopct='%0.2f%%', shadow=True,)

chart1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,frameChartsLT)
chart1.get_tk_widget().pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you soo much sir!! I honestly really appreciate you taking the time to help out!!!

Comment: @AlexLin if it helped, consider accepting the answer so the question can be closed.